# How GAE(standard) and GKE communucation is conducted?

Tags: google-app-engine, networking, google-kubernetes-engine

I created an application on GAE-standard environment.
Now, I need a static ip address to communicate  with an 3th party,
and an optimization of an egress communication via GKE application is on going.

I have tried 2 test.

1) GAE(standard) on project A → GKE on project A

```
  Simple rest communication took about 10 ms.
```

2) GAE(standard) on project A → GKE on project B

```
  Simple rest communication took about from 1 ms to 80ms.
```

By optimization, I would like to let the latency shorter.
In the above tests, GAE application is pointing an IP address, which is provided by one of GKE settings as external IP.

At this point, I guess the communication is utilizing an Internet.
In the official site and some other information, I should use the IP of Loadbalancer as internal one.

If I use internal one, does the latency of the communication become shorter
because that it's in google-network?

Or can I use VPC to accomplish the goal.
Any other information is welcome.